# phph - How to loop through a multidemsional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am attempting to return a list of teams along with the players on the team. Here is a shortened version of my array.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [team_id] => 1 
        [team_name] => Team1 
        [players] => Array ( 
             [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                 [n_name] => player1 ) 
             [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                 [n_name] => player2 )
     ) ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
        [team_id] => 2 
        [team_name] => Team2 
        [players] => Array ( 
             [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                 [n_name] => player3 ) 
             [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                 [n_name] => player4 )
     ) )
)
```

How would I approach looping through the teams and players to get something similar to:

```
TEAM_ID: 1
TEAM_NAME: Team1
PLAYERS: player1, player2

TEAM_ID: 2
TEAM_NAME: Team2
PLAYERS: player3, player4
```

A foreach within a foreach?

Comment: Can you please provide the code you wrote to have array structure like this?

Comment: I would say that this looks like more of an array of an object. Not multidimensional array.

Comment: That code is what is produced when using print_r().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($teams as $team) {
    echo 'TEAM_ID: ' . $team['team_id'] . '<br />';
    echo 'TEAM_NAME: ' . $team['team_name'] . '<br />';
    echo 'PLAYERS: ';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($team['players']); $i++) {
        echo $team['players'][$i]->n_name;

        if($i < count($team['players']) - 1) {
            echo ', ';
        }
    }

    echo '<br /><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct assumption. A foreach within a foreach.

```
Foreach($array as $value){
   //$value is now the inside array
   Foreach($value as $value2){
      //$value2 is the value of each variable of inside array
  }
}
```

Use echoes within the first foreach to express team names. Within the nested foreach to express player info.